# Close parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

I have a set of div's with some child elements.Inside parent div I have a hyperlink.
If I click the hyperlink, then i want to close the parent div  of the currently clicked link, not other div's.

Ex:

```
<div class="1"><a href="#" class="closeThis">close</a></div>
<div class="2"><a href="#" class="closeThis">close</a></div>
<div class="3"><a href="#" class="closeThis">close</a></div>
<div class="4"><a href="#" class="closeThis">close</a></div>
```

if I click the link inside the class="1" then i just want to hide the current parent of class="1" div, not other parent div.

Help me to fix .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
$("div a.closeThis").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: what if he has a link elsewhere inside a div? It will be gone too !!

Comment: @Darmen - I'd suggest `$('a.closeThis')` instead of `($"div a")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**Your links:**

```
<div class="1"><a href="#" class="closeThis" onclick="removeThis(this);">close</a></div>
<div class="2"><a href="#" class="closeThis" onclick="removeThis(this);">close</a></div>
<div class="3"><a href="#" class="closeThis" onclick="removeThis(this);">close</a></div>
<div class="4"><a href="#" class="closeThis" onclick="removeThis(this);">close</a></div>

<script>
  function removeThis(field)
  {
    $(field).parent().hide();
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** You could also use `remove()` instead of `hide()` as shown above. Thanks

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply... there is some problem. The code closes the other remaning Div's also.
I want to close the parent div  of the currently clicked link, not the other div's. The class name of link is same for all the Div's.